# How to calculate probability from a conditional probability table?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know how to calculate probabilities from joint probability tables, but not from conditional probability tables. From the below table how can I calculate P(C)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, as there is insufficient information.

By the Law of Total Probability: $$\mathsf P(C=c)~=~\mathsf P(C=c\mid A=0)\,\mathsf P(A=0)+\mathsf P(C=c\mid A=1)\,\mathsf P(A=1)$$

The first factor of each term comes from the table, but you don't have $\mathsf P(A=0)$ nor $\mathsf P(A=1)$.